# Getting an error message while trying to execute Router Component in ReactJS using Jest and Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, react-router, jestjs, enzyme

We use React Router Library in ReactJS to navigate to the different pages in the application but while executing the unit test case through Jest and Enzyme

Getting the Following exceptions:

```
Failed context type: The context `router` is marked as required in `Switch`, but its value is `undefined`.

Failed context type: The context `router` is marked as required in `Link`, but its value is `undefined`.
```

Send me your suggestions

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If you want us to help, please provide us with some [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for us to have more info.

Answer (score 1):

Mount component inside either `<MemoryRouter />` or `<BrowserRouter />` from react-router-dom using `mount()` and if you are using redux also then mount `<MemoryRouter />` inside `<Provider />`.

```
mount(
    <MemoryRouter>
       <Component />
    </MemoryRouter>
)
```

Or in case of redux

```
mount(
    <Provider store={yourDummyStore}>
        <MemoryRouter>
            <Component />
        </MemoryRouter>
    </Provider>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Mount your component inside a `<MemoryRouter />` from react-router-dom. The error says those components expect to "live" as descendants of a `Router` component (they get the routing state via React context).

`mount(<MemoryRouter><YourCompThatUsesRouter /></MemoryRouter>)`

Will do the trick.